# Automatization of change of global variable in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, global-variables

I have a very long script in a jupyter notebook with lots of computations with many cells (around 50+) which goes like this

```
var1 = "a" # could take value of "a", "b", "c" or "d"
var2 = "1" # could take value of "1", "2", "3" or "4"

if var1 == "a":
    if var2 == "1":
        # performs computations set 1
        print("statement 1")
    elif var2 == "2":
        # performs computations set 2
        print("statement 3")

var1 == "b":
    if var2 == "1":
        # performs computations set 3
        print("statement 3")
    elif var2 == "2":
        # performs computations set 4
        print("statement 4")
```

Each run of code takes about 2 minutes.
Is the combination of `var1` and `var2` is long (around 30) which means that, If I want to run the script for the 30 computations, I have to manually define `var1` and `var2` at each run. Is there a way to automatize the process?

Comment: This `if var1 = "a":` is not valid Python

Comment: Did you mean: ‘if var1 == "b":’?

Comment: Are the computations different for every variation?

Comment: Sorry. indeed I meant `if var1 == "a":`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're mistaken. Using `if` use `==` instead of `=`.
To solve your problem you can use the following condition statements:

```py
var1, var2 = 'a', '1'
cond = var1 + var2
if cond == 'a1':
    print('statement 1')
elif cond == 'a2':
    print('statement 2')
elif cond == 'b1':
    print('statement 3')
// etc...
```

or if you can present statements more algorithmic/mathematically, please, do it (I mean if conditions vary on `var1` and `var2` more commonly then don't forget about this). For example: if you need print letter `var1` `var2` times then just use `print(int(var2)*var1)`